# Android How to use this HorizontalListView to replace Gallery?

Tags: android, listview, gallery, horizontal-scrolling

I am currently using Gallery to display a list of items. Everything work fine except the center locking feature which I don't like. I found this HorizontalListView implementation from here http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34 and want using it to replace the Android Gallery. I downloaded the HorizontalListView.java, put it in my project and change Gallery to HorizontalListView, but when I run the app, nothing show up. The items of the Gallery (HorizontalListView now) is set by using ArrayAdapter. Did I set up anything wrong? Here's the code:

Layout HorizontalListView:

```
    <com.myapp.HorizontalListView
      android:id="@+id/related"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="#ebebeb" >
    </com.myapp.HorizontalListView>
```

HorizontalListView item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/gameicon"
    android:layout_width="120dip"
    android:layout_height="120dip"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/iconbig" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gamename"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter for items:

```
public class RelatedListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GameInfo> {

private ArrayList<GameInfo> items;
public static HashMap<String, String> relatedImageMap;

public RelatedListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<GameInfo> items) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    this.items = items;
    if (relatedImageMap == null)
        relatedImageMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.related_items, null);
    }

    GameInfo game = items.get(position);
    if (game != null) {
        TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.gamename);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.gameicon);
        if (name != null) {         
            name.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ebebeb"));
            name.setText(NewDetailActivity.TruncateString(game.getName(), 8) );
        }
        if (icon != null) {
            icon.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ebebeb"));
            if (EfficientAdapter.imageMap.containsKey(game.getId())) {
                String filePath = EfficientAdapter.imageMap.get(game
                        .getId());
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                icon.setImageBitmap(bm);
            } else if (relatedImageMap.containsKey(game.getId())) {
                String filePath = relatedImageMap.get(game.getId());
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                icon.setImageBitmap(bm);
            } else {
                String storagePath = Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                        + getContext().getResources().getString(
                                R.string.imgCacheFolder);
                String image = game.getImgUrl().replaceAll(
                        "[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+", "");
                String filePath = storagePath + image;
                EfficientAdapter.LoadImageFromWebOperations(game.getImgUrl(),
                        filePath, null);
                if (relatedImageMap != null) {
                    synchronized (relatedImageMap) {
                        relatedImageMap.put(game.getId(), filePath);
                    }
                }
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                icon.setImageBitmap(bm);
            }
        }
    }

    return v;
}
```

}

And in my Activity:

```
HorizontalListView related = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.related);
data = new ArrayList<GameInfo>();
adap = new RelatedListAdapter(this, R.layout.related_items, data);
related.setAdapter(adap);
```

If I change HorizontalListView to Gallery, everything work fine and the list is shown. But using HorizontalListView, nothing show up. Can anyone help me out with this?

**EDIT:** I found out something different now. The HorizontalListView did show up, but not the first time I open it. For example I have 3 tab and HorizontalListView in tab 3. When I start activity, it show tab 1. Then I click tab 3, nothing show up. I changed to tab 1 or tab 2, then return to tab 3, the list is showing now. Strange huh? Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also used the HorizontalListView in the before. But it is too hard to adapt to suite my particular use case.

Then I found this class HorizontalScrollView. It is defined in android SDK - much more easy to use and versatile.

Comment: The downside of the HorizontalScrollView is that you can't use adapters, therefore if you have a big list of items to show, all of them will be loaded in memory, no lazy-loading.